# Jstree: Alert message when using unique plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jstree

I would like to create a pop up alert message in Jstree when a folder with the same name is detected in the tree. I am already using `unique` plugin, however I would like to have an alert message in case a user renames or creates a folder that already exists.
Any suggestion?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

A late response but you'd probably do something like this:

```
.jstree(
    {
        ...
        "unique": {
            "duplicate": function (name, counter) {
                alert('duplicate node added: ' + name);
                return name; // This would just return the duplicate name to use as the node is created
            }
        }

    }
```

Just keep in mind that there are other events that could cause a change to the name as it's getting created (such as "action" from a "contextmenu".